# Incorrect result of Math.Round() function in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

In following code if I encounter some incorrect result while I applied following input to the code.

Code is as follow.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox(TextBox1.Text & " = Val(" & Val(TextBox1.Text) & ") = Math.Round(" & Math.Round(Val(TextBox1.Text)) & ")")
End Sub
```

Input applied => Output Received

3.5 => 4

5.5 => 6

4.5 => 4

Math.Round function returns correct result in first two inputs, but third result is incorrect.

Please help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Math.Round(4.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> If the fractional component of d is halfway between two integers, one
>   of which is even and the other odd, the even number is returned.

You can try to use:

```
Math.Round(4.5, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

You can check [MidpointRounding Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx)

[image]

Comment: What should be the code if expected result of code should as follow. if x.5 then result would be x+1?